# WebBrowser Control - Invoke Script Problems with JavaScript Button

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control, invokescript

I am trying to login to a website.  I am able to fill out the form correctly with all of the connection information, but I cannot get the page to login.  The button is a link without a name or id, so I can't click it directly.  I have been working on invokeScript() stuff, but that doesn't seem to work either.  This is the button code:

```
<div style="float:left; width:50px; margin: 0px auto 0px auto; text-align:center;">
    <div id="loginBtn">
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; font-size: 10px; color:#FFFFFF;" onClick="javascript: LoginSubmit(event, true);" tabindex="3">
            Log In
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I  click a link like that?

I have tried stuff like this:

```
webBrowserControl.InvokeScript("LoginSubmit", "true" );

webBrowserControl.InvokeScript("LoginSubmit(event, true)");
```

and

```
webBrowserControl.InvokeScript("LoginSubmit", new object[] { new string[] { "event", "true" } });
```

Comment: This question doesn't even include what is (was) the error. Not useful when googling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be missing **Document**, like so:

`webBrowserControl.Document.InvokeScript(name, args)`

if not try invoking the script with [this wrapper method](http://notions.okuda.ca/2009/06/11/calling-javascript-in-a-webbrowser-control-from-c/), extract:

```
private object MyInvokeScript(string name, params object[] args) 
{ 
    return webBrowserControl.Document.InvokeScript(name, args); 
}

…

int x = 50; 
int y = 100; 
MyInvokeScript("LoginSubmit",x, y);
```

Comment: That worked, but not without the .Document in the method.  I had to go webBrowserControl.InvokeScript.  I got logged in though, so that's good!

Comment: Good stuff, glad I could help

Comment: Yeah, thanks.  I'll accept the answer in a bit.  It's too early still.  You already received my +1 though.

Comment: Nice answer, but he clearly specified he's using a WPF Browser, so it is obvious that there is no `.Document` member before the `InvokeScript` method.